# Monotouch get UiPickerView selected item

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uipickerview

I made a programmatically custon uipicker inside a actionsheet, now I need to set a text field with the item selected of the picker. With a datepicker I get the value like this:

```
 actionSheetDatePicker.DatePicker.ValueChanged += (s, e) => {
                this.lblCheckOut.Text = f.ToString ((s as UIDatePicker).Date);
            };
```

Now I'm trying to do the same thing with my UIPickerView but I don't have a ValueChanged Method.

Does anyone can help me to get the value of the item selected with my picker.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate on Jason's answer, here is a code sample using a UIPickerView as a custom date picker. Hope it helps someone.

```
UIPickerView datePicker = new UIPickerView ();
var mod = new DatePickerDataModel ();
datePicker.Model = mod;

mod.ValueChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
    _selectedDate = mod.SelectedItem;
};


class DatePickerDataModel : UIPickerViewModel
    {
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ValueChanged;

        public List<DateTime> Items { get; private set; }

        public DateTime SelectedItem {
            get { return Items [selectedIndex]; }
        }

        int selectedIndex = 0;

        public DatePickerDataModel ()
        {
            var items = new List<DateTime> ();
            for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
                items.Add (DateTime.Now.Subtract (TimeSpan.FromDays (i)));
            }
            Items = items;
        }

        public override nint GetRowsInComponent (UIPickerView picker, nint component)
        {
            return Items.Count;
        }

        public override nint GetComponentCount (UIPickerView picker)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        public override void Selected (UIPickerView picker, nint row, nint component)
        {
            selectedIndex = (int)row;
            ValueChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty());
        }

        public override string GetTitle (UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
        {
            var t = Items [(int)row];
            var m = t.ToString ("MMM");
            var d = t.ToString ("ddd");
            return $"{d} {m} {t.Day}";
        }

        public override nfloat GetRowHeight (UIPickerView picker, nint component)
        {
            return 44;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

UIPickerViewDelegate has a Selected method which you can use to raise an event when the user selects a value.